# How to generate Oauth2.0 token for Stormpath

Tags: go, stormpath

Can someone help me in generating a access-token for Stormpath.
I'm following the steps mentioned [storms api doc.](http://docs.stormpath.com/guides/api-key-management/)But stuck with error code 404(The requested resource does not exist).

I'm using end point (http://api.stormpath.com/v1/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials) to get the tokens and passing all HEADER values as mentioned in API document. Have some used it before ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work at Stormpath and can help you with this.

The answer is that you need to use one of our SDKs on your server.  At this time we don't support token creation directly from our API.  Instead you will need to expose this functionality on your server by using one of our SDKs.  The SDK will work with your Stormpath Application to create the tokens and serve them from your serve.

This section of the documentation has examples:

http://docs.stormpath.com/guides/api-key-management/#using-the-stormpath-sdk-to-authenticate-and-generate-tokens-for-your-api-keys

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @robertjd for answering, does this mean that i have to add a  server may be in node/ python/ java to generate tokens.Also, stormpath mentions couple of premature go-sdk (..correct me if I'm wrong), is there any chances stormpath pushing for it.

Comment: Yep, our Node, Python and Java SDKs all have support for this - each one has it's own documentation that describes it in detail